# Eager load expired entries

Tags: eager-loading, status

By default eager loading only returns live entries. Is it possible to grab expired only.

I've got this... But I only want expired `relatedVenue`:

```
{% set ideas = craft.entries().section('ideas').with(['stListicles', 'stListicles.relatedVenue']) %}
```

Possible?

I've already tried this:

```
{% set ideas = craft.entries().section('ideas').status('live').with([
    'stListicles',
    ['stListicles.relatedVenue', { status: 'expired, disabled, pending' }]
]) %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is an Entries field in a Matrix block, the syntax is:

```twig
{% set ideas = craft.entries()
    .section('ideas')
    .status('live')
    .with([
        ['matrixField.blockType:entriesField', { status: ['not', 'live'] }]
    ])
    .all() %}
```

Change `matrixField.blockType:entriesField` to match your fields, of course :)

Documentation is here - https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#eager-loading-elements-related-to-matrix-blocks

Comment: Thanks @Oli, it's a SuperTable but I managed to find what I needed from the link you provided and its now working: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#defining-custom-parameters-on-eager-loaded-elements